# Problem with transfer objects between contexts

Tags: c++, events, bitmap, mfc, windows-ce

I try to make some easy application which scrolling ECG singal which is drawing on bitmap grid. Environment which I use is Visual Studio 2013 with C++ MFC.
My problem is with transfer gdi object like LineTo or Rectangle() function from dcMemory to my main device context (cdc). Before I make similar application using WinAPI and all go well. I spent a lot time with studying msdn and looking answer with google, and I have no idea why only bitmap from Bitmap.LoadBitmapW(IDB_BITMAP2) is printing. Can anybody help me?

Message when button from menu was calling:

```
 void CToradex_MFC_BitmapView::OnBitmapDraw()
    {
        Bitmap.LoadBitmapW(IDB_BITMAP2);
        cdc.CreateDC(L"DISPLAY", NULL, NULL, NULL);
        dcMemory.CreateCompatibleDC(&cdc);
        LoadData();
        GetObject(Bitmap, sizeof(bmpInfo), &bmpInfo);
        dcMemory.SelectObject(&Pen);
        dcMemory.Rectangle(100, 100, 200, 200);
        dcMemory.LineTo(100, 300);
        dcMemory.SelectObject(&Bitmap);
        druk.DrawECG(&dcMemory, pointer, 3, SIGN_LEN);
    
    }
```

---

Message on mouse button down:

```
void CToradex_MFC_BitmapView::OnLButtonDown(UINT,CPoint)
{   

    CToradex_MFC_BitmapDoc* pDoc = GetDocument();
    ASSERT_VALID(pDoc);
    POINT p;
    GetCursorPos(&p);
    x_start = p.x;
    y_start = p.y;
}
```

---

Message on mouse move:

```
void CToradex_MFC_BitmapView::OnMouseMove(UINT, CPoint)
{   
POINT d;

//CDC * pDC = this->GetDC();
//this->GetClientRect(&rect);
//rect = CRect(rect.left, rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom);
if (GetCursorPos(&d))
{
    move_x = d.x - x_start;
    move_y = d.y - y_start;
    cdc.BitBlt(move_x, move_y, bmpInfo.bmWidth, bmpInfo.bmHeight, &dcMemory, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    x_start = d.x;
    y_start = d.y;
//Invalidate();
Sleep(10);
}
```

Below link for all .cpp file:

https://pastebin.com/h7hcLJbz

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. It's unclear what you hope the `OnMouseMove` message handler to do, but calling `Sleep(10)` is most definitely not one of the things you should be doing.

Comment: @IInspectable This is only 3 function which I calling in this simple case. In MouseMove event i want to move bitmap with drawing signal on them with mouse move. Bitmap is rendering but whitout signal

Comment: Presumably, there's also a `WM_PAINT` handler. As posted we have no way of knowing what that does. We don't know what `druk` is either, or what `DrawECG` does. Likewise, we don't know what `Pen` is, or why you are ignoring the return value of `SelectObject`. If you need help you're going to have to put in some work and produce a [mcve]. See [ask] for help.

Comment: I am so sorry for ay polish name DrawECG function is responsible for drawing a ECG signal on device context is my own fuction. druk is object of class which is responsible for signal operation

Comment: https://pastebin.com/h7hcLJbz

Comment: *"Here's ALL of the code"* is not a [mcve]. It fails the *"minimal"* part.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select a bitmap into your DC first, then draw on top of it:

```
dcMemory.SelectObject(&Bitmap);
dcMemory.SelectObject(&Pen);
dcMemory.Rectangle(100, 100, 200, 200);
dcMemory.LineTo(100, 300);
druk.DrawECG(&dcMemory, pointer, 3, SIGN_LEN);
```

Comment: is still same effect. Is like Rectangle, LineTo or DrawECG doesn't save on dcMemory

Comment: @SunriseAvenue - where and how is that `dcMemory` declared? Where else is it modified? What does `druk.DrawECG()` do? I now second @IInspectable's request for a minimal example

Comment: Please take a look for this paste and tell me that is enough...
https://pastebin.com/h7hcLJbz

Comment: Your code works, kind of. It draws the content of the bitmap with the rectangle on top. HOWEVER, it draws on the screen's DC instead of your `CToradex_MFC_BitmapView`. Also, it draws on every mouse move, regardless of the button state (down or not). Please take suggestions from the comments to your question and do all the drawings in response to `WM_PAINT` message (`OnPaint()`). In `OnMouseMove()` you should calculate the offset and invalidate the window